# Convert String to OpCode

Tags: c#, .net, cil, opcode, mono.cecil

I'm attempting to make an instruction editor in C# and I'm stuck on creating instructions. I need to be able to convert a string to an OpCode with Mono.Cecil but it doesn't seem to be able to do that. If it's any easier I could create a `Dictionary<string, OpCode>` and populate that by enumerating through the OpCodes in `OpCodes`, however `OpCodes` is only class that contains the OpCodes as variables instead of in a list (I think this might be for .NET 1 support) preventing me from enumerating through them. That's where I arrive to the problem, how can I either convert a string to an OpCode, or enumerate through every OpCode (whichever is easier/faster).

Comment: Enumerate it through reflection if performance is not a problem.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel How would I get the `Mono.Cecil.Cil.OpCode`s via that though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection would help you here if performance is not a problem.

Here's how you go.

```
var opCodes = typeof(OpCodes)
                    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Where(x=> x.FieldType == typeof(OpCode))
                    .Select(x=> (OpCode)x.GetValue(null))
                    .ToArray();

foreach(var opcode in opCodes)
{
   //Do whatever with opcode
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely a fast response for a Mono.Cecil related question considering the lack of documentation and programmers.